# Axion-photon coupling

Tags: particle-physics, axion

The QCD axion couples to the photon through a term proportional to $a F_{\mu\nu} \tilde{F}^{\mu\nu}$. I understand that this term is due to the electromagnetic anomaly. I am interested in two questions :

1. Why does the axion not also couple to $a F_{\mu\nu} F^{\mu\nu}$?
2. What is the simplest way to calculate the prefactor for the term proportional to $a F_{\mu\nu} \tilde{F}^{\mu\nu}$ ? I understand that the axion couples to quarks (since the axion is the phase of the PQ scalar $\Phi$ which has Yukawa couplings in e.g the DFSZ or KSFZ models), and quarks couples to gluons so that there is a triangle diagram with a quark running in the loop which gives rise to an operator coupling the axion to two photons. However how can I see simply that this operator is necessarily proportional to $a F_{\mu\nu} \tilde{F}^{\mu\nu}$ ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Are you in complete, unequivocal, comfortable, and unhesitating control of the celebrated original flavor-chiral anomaly calculation and effective lagrangian for neutral pion decay? There is hardly a point in discussing axions unless the answer is yes.

Comment: So the divergence of the axial current will *have* to be a pseudoscalar, not a scalar... your (1). The coefficient of the aγγ diagram will be proportional to the coefficient in that divergence, just like the corresponding term of the πγγ effective lagrangian. Replicate the determination of that.

Answer (score 1):

In electromagnetic theory, the Maxwell-Lorentz Lagrangian density is given by
$$ = ½ ε_0 (E^2 - B^2 c^2)$$
which, when written in tensor form, becomes
$$ = -¼ \sqrt{|g|} ε₀ c g^{μρ} g^{νσ} F_{μν} F_{ρσ} = -¼ \sqrt{|g|} ε_0 c F_{μν} F^{μν}$$
so that would actually be the *permittivity* $ε_0$ you're turning into a field, rather than its axial counterpart.

I don't know the names of any theories that have permittivity promoted to a field, but if you were to write down the 5D version of Einstein's equations, *making no special assumptions about the "corner" metric coefficient $g_{55}$*, the result would be equivalent to the Einstein-Maxwell equations, with permittivity promoted to a field (arising ultimately from $g_{55}$), plus another equation for this field.

For electromagnetism, a general Lagrangian density that is gauge-invariant and Lorentz invariant, reduces to a function $ = (ℑ,)$ of the Lorentz invariants $ℑ = ½ (E^2 - B^2 c^2)$ and $ = ·$. The corresponding differential coefficients can be defined by $δ = ε δℑ + θ δ$ leading to the reduction $δ = ·δ - ·δ$, where $ = ε + θ$, $ = εc² - θ$, along with the Maxwell equations $∇· = ρ$ and $∇× - ∂/∂t = $, if sources for charge density $ρ$ and current density $$ are also included.

All of this can be combined as $ℑ + ic = ½| + ic|^2$ and $ + i/c = (ε - iθ/c) ( + ic)$. (The axion model uses the opposite sign for the axial coefficient $θ$, from what I'm using here). So, the axion could be considered as the imaginary part of the permittivity promoted to a field.

All of these considerations generalize to gauge fields, without any real changes of substance, but are easier to describe for the Maxwell field.